# Запятая перед тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Вопрос перерос уже третью тему. Увы, но ответа так и нет.

Суть проблемы и обзор "предыдущих серий".
~1. behemothus высказал утвеждение, что правила постановки запятой и тире при их встрече нигде в полном виде не прописаны. Конкретно нигде не прописаны случаи поглощения одного знака другим (тире поглощает запятую) . Есть ещё спорные моменты, пока не о них.
~2. В качесте возражения были приведены (Ларf) следующие соображения:
а) никаких сомнений, чем открыли - тем и закрывайте.
б) ссылка на правило "при встрече запятой тире сначала ставится запятая".
в) предположение, что все дело - в т. н. авторской пунктуации.
*Если исказил мысль, то невольно, нижайше прошу дать точную формулировку.*
~3.
На возражение а) были приведены многочисленные примеры, в которым запятая не требуется либо (другими словами) поглощается тире. При необходимости могу дать ещё.
Возражение б) на мой взляд совершенно не относится к вопросу о "поглощении", а лишь утверждает, что *в случае сохранения обоих знаков сначала идет запятая*.
Возражение в) не выглядит убедительным, поскольку число примеров такого поглощения явно превышает число возможных авторских вольностей. И еще - поскольку отдельные разнозненные правила о поглощении прописаны даже в "правилах-56". Но именно - отдельные, например о том, что тире может (или должно?) *поглощать первую, открывающую, из двух парных запятых*.

Таким образом вопрос остался открытым (как и все предыдущие попытки связать концы с концами). 
***Вопрос все тот же. Где описаны все случаи поглощения тире запятой или хотя бы кто может внятно и непротиворечиво их сформулировать?***

Два примера на поглощение из нацкорпуса:
*Вам кажется, что заржавела металлическая ось ручки терморегулятора[,] ― обратитесь к врачу по месту жительства* - закрывающая запятая поглощена тире.

*Другой раз ― это было в конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день[,] ― ребята сидели в скверике на скамейке, возле загородки с песком, и разговаривали о своих делах.* В. Ф. Панова. Конспект романа (1965) - аналогично.

Это только случаи **явного** отступления от "правила" о необходимости закрывать все открытое тем же знаком.

Comment: Запятые здесь необходимы. В первом случае - закрыть придаточное. Тире на своем основании: сложносочиненное предложение. Переделаем: Вам кажется ржавчина - обратитесь...

После "день" нужна запятая, чтобы закрыть обособл. оборот. Тире парное обособляет вставку.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не совсем корректно преподносить отрывки из комментариев как цельную точку зрения по вопросу, все-таки комментарии всегда конкретны по отношению к предложению или предыдущему комментарию .

Теперь по сути. В справочнике Лопатина (**Институт русского языка. Академия наук** )
 § 156. **При сочетании в тексте тире и запятой** **вначале ставится запятая (***запятая закрывает впереди стоящую конструкцию***), затем тире**: Сводки погоды — замирало всё в доме, когда начинали их передавать, — казались однообразными и тупыми, потому что в них не было явлений и бурно нарастающих признаков начинающейся весны (Сол.); Тропинка отвернула вправо, но он, по совету пастушонка, продолжал идти по скошенному лугу, пока не натолкнулся на прясло, огибавшее мужицкие огороды, — дальше пошел задами (Фад.).

§ 157. **При сочетании в тексте запятой и многоточия, запятой и двоеточия запятая опускается (поглощается многоточием или двоеточием**): — А, например, как же цена, хотя, впрочем, это такой предмет... что о цене даже странно... (Г.) — поглощена запятая перед придаточной частью; Прошел пять шагов, обернулся и махнул Илье рукой, будто поясняя: я от тебя ушел, но помню о тебе (Щерб.) — двоеточие поглотило запятую, закрывающую деепричастный оборот

Для меня ясно, что раз про двоеточие говорится, что оно поглощает  запятую,  -значит поглощает. Про тире этого не говорится, а четко написано: запятая закрывает предыдущую конструкцию. Значит такого поглощения не происходит (как правило).
В предложении *"Вам кажется, что заржавела металлическая ось ручки терморегулятора ― обратитесь к врачу по месту жительства"*,на мой взгляд, ошибка. Запятая должна быть.

В предложении *"Другой раз ― это было в конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день[,] ― ребята сидели в скверике на скамейке, возле загородки с песком, и разговаривали о своих делах"* запятой может и не быть, если здесь однородные обстоятельства, или её все же надо поставить, если видеть здесь уточняющее обстоятельство.

Еще из статьи "Употребление тире в простом и сложном предложении" Николенковой Н. В.

*ВНИМАНИЕ!
Перед тире во всех рассмотренных выше случаях по условиям контекста может оказаться запятая. Это возможно, если перед местом постановки тире находится обособленный член предложения или придаточное предложение. В этом случая пишущий ставит два не связанных между собой знака: запятую, закрывающую один оборот, и тире, стоящее между подлежащим и сказуемым.
Наиболее распространенной **ошибкой пишущих будет непостановка запятой перед тире**.*

Так в правилах. В практике по-другому.  Это нормально. Возможно, это так и останется ошибкой. А может быть, количество перерастет в качество и в следующем издании правил мы увидим строчки о том, что тире поглощает  запятую.

Comment: >Не совсем корректно преподносить отрывки из комментариев как цельную точку зрения по вопросу
А она у Вас есть, цельная точка зрения? Я с удовыольствием её послушаю.
"Теперь по сути".
§ 156. - не по теме, уже тири раза говорил.
§ 157. - это вооще не про тире. С двоеточием, слава Богу разобрались, надеюсь Вы не будете настаивать на закрывающей запятой перед ним?

>если здесь однородные обстоятельства  
Вы серьёзно полагаете, что запятой может не бвть в тексте "В конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день[,] ребята сидели..."?

Comment: Еще из статьи "Употребление тире в простом и сложном предложении" Николенковой Н. В.

Comment: Я принял ответ больше от безвыходности. Ни списка, ни формулировок случае так никто и не дал.

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя "поглощение" встречается в трех лишь случаях:

1. Тире при вводных словах употребляется в следующих случаях:
   1) если вводное словосочетание образует неполную конструкцию (пропущено какое-либо слово, восстанавливаемое из контекста), то вместо одной запятой обычно ставится тире: Макаренко неоднократно подчёркивал, что педагогика основана, с одной стороны, на безграничном доверии к человеку, а с другой – на высоких к нему требованиях; Чичиков велел остановиться по двум причинам: с одной стороны, чтобы дать отдохнуть лошадям, с другой – что бы и самому отдохнуть и подкрепиться – запятая перед придаточной частью «поглощается» тире; С одной стороны, важно было принять срочное решение, но требовалась осторожность – с другой.
2. При «встрече» многоточия с запятой последняя поглощается многоточием, которое указывает не только на пропуск слов, но и на пропуск знака препинания: Жена его… впрочем, они были совершенно довольны друг другом (Г.).
3. Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов в этих конструкциях требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а тире или ставится, или опускается. Ср.: Наряду с иными стихийными бедствиями, как-то: пожар, град, начисто выбивающий хлебные поля, ненастье или, наоборот, великая сушь, – есть в деревне ещё одно бедствие (Сол.) – запятая закрывает обособленный оборот с предложным сочетанием наряду с; Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как то:муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки (Г.) – запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.

В остальных случаях либо запятая и тире ставятся по своим основаниям, либо как единый знак, либо: тире опускается (не "поглощается")при приложении, если по условиям должна быть запятая после второго тире.

Comment: Спасибо, я видел Розенталя. Вся беда, что нигде не сказано, что этот список исчерпывающ. А коли так, то на каздого Розенталя свой Мильчин найдется. Помните историю с точкой после кавычек? Аналогичный случай. Розенталь (и правила-56) описывают какие-то случаи, но не говорят, что других ьыть не может. Вот Мильчин и начиинает додумывать. и кто прав - не очень понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Тире запятую не поглощает.  Каждая на своем основании должна быть поставлена.

Comment: Это неправда. Во всяком случае - формулировка неполная.

Вот вам случай, прямо оговоренный правилами:
Примечание. Если после тире стоят слова, выделяющиеся по существующим правилам запятыми (например, вводные слова), то первая запятая опускается, например:
Сосна, ель, пихта, кедр – словом, все породы хвойных деревьев встречаются в сибирской тайге. http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=oszp

Comment: Ко всему прочему логика "на своём основании поставлена" не выдерживает критики в сравнении, например, с двоеточием. Там тоже каждый знак стоит на своих основаниях, тем не менее двоеточие поглощает запятую. Так что прежде чем давать подобные формулировки, стоит хотя бы уточнить, чем тире отличается от двоеточия и остальных знаков (точки, точки с заяптой, закрывающей скобки, закрывающей кавычки и т.д), что оно тире, такое особенное.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто эстетически - запятая с последующим дефисом выглядит совершенно убого. Я бы стал так писать только в принудительном порядке, например если бы мой редактор мне явным образом об этом сказал (говорю как переводчик, создавший множество текстов). Господам прескриптивистам предлагаю расслабиться и посмотреть на язык как на средство передачи информации.

**Обновление**

Правильнее будет сказать: Запятая с последующим тире выглядит совершенно убого.

Опять же, эта запятая нечего не добавляет в плане ясности. С другой стороны, прескриптивиста по определению не интересует ясность.

Comment: Вы дефис от тире отличаете, г-н переводчик?

Comment: Сорри. Вы правы, я был не прав. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, я очень многого не понимаю, но лично мне кажется, что если, например, какая-то уточняющая часть предложения находится посередине и обособляется тире с обеих сторон, а при опускании это части по ощущениям запятая нужна, то она ставится.
Например:
"Я шёл — как мне казалось, в верном направлении, — но племянница даже не думала сходить с места". → "Я шёл,  но племянница даже не думала сходить с места".
С другой стороны:
"Ты бежал — по крайней мере, так казалось со стороны — слишком широкими шагами". → "Ты бежал слишком широкими шагами".
Как-то так.