# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в данном примере запятая перед тире?

"Когда я приеду в деревню к бабушке, — этой ли зимой? — я буду ездить целыми днями на лыжах."

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая отделяет придаточное предложение от главного

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Я тоже была уверена, что запятая нужна. Но во многих справочниках находила пример без запятой: "Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё непопадается (Щерб.)" Не могу понять в чём дело. Почему здесь не стоит запятая?

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=97  Это сочетание запятой и тире, необходимое по условиям контекста Вы взяли с сайта,где много ошибок, даже не с глаголом слитно, нет двоеточия:   http://socialrost.ru/2012/02/29/osnovnyie_sintaksicheskie_edinitsyi_slovoforma-attachment/95/   "В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие."

Comment: Да, Вы правы. 
Но я почему-то вообще нигде не встречала подобной конструкции, как в моём примере. Видела лишь вроде: "Она посмотрела на бардак, который был в комнате, - какой кошмар! – и руки сами собой опустились" Но это, вроде, не совсем мой пример. Здесь вторая запятая необходима, чтобы закрыть "который был в комнате"

Comment: Кстати, нашла оригинал повести Галины Щербаковой. Там "не" с глаголом пишется раздельно, ошибки нет. Но у неё всё же запятая перед тире не стоит. "Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё не попадается" И я обратила внимание, что обычно запятые ставятся не перед первым тире, а перед вторым. Но т.к. у меня перед вторым тире стоит "?", может он и "поглотил" эту запятую? Извините, если пишу чепуху, но я всё никак до конца не пойму правила вставных конструкций.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то это не совсем ответ, а размышления на тему...
Но, полагаю, они более чем просто комментарий.

> И я обратила внимание, что обычно запятые ставятся не перед первым тире...

Так и есть. На самом деле это зависит от структуры предложения, к какой из частей относится обособление в парных тире. Обычно получается, что к первой и запятая ставится после второго тире. На что "юридических" причин может и не быть, это когда обособляемая конструкция относится скорее ко второй части.
Вопросительный или восклицательный знак безусловно поглощает запятую, вопрос в том, насколько вообще допустимо его использование в середине фразы.  Но уж коли он там есть, то запятая, если она должна бы быть рядом с ним, безусловно "поглощается".

Что же касается общих правил, то на мой взгляд, современный орфографический свод не до конца раскрывает эту тему. Можете считать это личным мнением, но я уже лет десять безуспешно пытаюсь найти исчерпывающий источник или хотя бы сформулировать самостоятельно все нюансы на тему "встреча запятой и тире".

Даже на этом форуме пытался поднять вопрос - бесполезно. 
[Запятая перед тире](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)

Так что лучше руководствоваться интуицией - и ставить её при первой возможности.
В данном случае я крепко сомневаюсь, что не будь вопросительного знака, запятая ставилась бы именно там, а не перед вторым тире.

Comment: Да... неоднозначная ситуация получается. Где бы найти ответ?.. А Вы бы в моём примере поставили запятую?

Comment: Да, поставил бы. Но, как сказал, более интуитивно, чем следуя конкретным правилам. Рядом с вопросительным знаком, где ей бы самое место, её ставить нельзя, а больше негде.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, за то, что поделились своими размышлениями.

Comment: Да не за что. Помощи, боюсь, от меня немного, да я на благодарности не падкий. Мне самому этот вопрос жить спокойно не даёт.)))

Я вот настолько заумную формулировку в ответе дал, что сам еле разобрался, что же сказать хотел. ))) Поправил только сейчас.

Comment: Можно вставную конструкцию оформить не тире,а скобками. И запятую поставить после скобки.

Comment: Да, про скобки я знаю, спасибо, но меня интересует именно случай с тире.