# "Который", "что", запятая и тире

Tags: пунктуация

Понятно, что если перед тире стоит причастный или деепричастный оборот, то ставится запятая и тире. А конструкции с "который", "что", "чтобы" тоже надо все закрывать? Слышал, что в некоторых случаях, тире съедает запятую. Это в каких?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А конструкции с "который", "что", "чтобы" тоже надо все закрывать?

Сзади - всегда (почти - см. ниже), спереди - нет.
Если обособляемая или отделяемая с помощью тире часть начинается с конструкции "внутреннего" обособления, то запятая перед первым тире не ставится.

Пример искать сейчас не буду, держите мой.

> Пример искать не буду - чтобы это сделать, надо много времени.

(b-s)

"Чтобы это сделать" - требует обособления - с двух сторон, естественно. Но первая запятая "съедена" тире.

> Слышал, что в некоторых случаях, тире съедает запятую. Это в каких?

Правильно слышали. К Вашим примерам (на **придаточные** с "который", "чтобы" и т. п.) это прямого отношения не имеет, речь о другом. О закрывающей запятой, "съедаемой" в некоторых случаях тире.

Вот чтоб далеко не искать.

> Когда профессор приказал ему: "Не бросай объедки на пол" - неожиданно ответил: "Отлезь, гнида".

(МАБ, СС)

Тире поглотило запятую, требуемую не только по мотивам сложного предложения (что было бы понятно), но и по мотивам прямой речи, что вообще уникально. Признаю, в разных изданиях этот фрагмент оформляется пунктуационно по-разному, но приведенный вариант как минимум имеет право на существование.

Что еще могу признать, полного, исчерпывающего списка (или инструкции, свода правил) для таких случаев никто никогда не составлял. Поэтому наблюдается разнобой.

Я об этом писал и тут, и в других местах неоднократно, но воз, как вы понимаете, и ныне там.

Вот тут более или менее содержательно.
[Запятая перед тире](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706)

И там же - еще два примера из нацкорпуса.

> *Вам кажется, что заржавела металлическая ось ручки терморегулятора[,] ― обратитесь к врачу по месту жительства*

Закрывающая запятая поглощена тире.

> *Другой раз ― это было в конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день[,] ― ребята сидели в скверике на скамейке, возле загородки с песком, и разговаривали о своих делах.*

В. Ф. Панова. Конспект романа (1965) - аналогично.

(+)
GalinAvanesova элементарно не поняла вопроса. Даже комментировать не хочется. Согласен, термин "поглощение" не общепринятый, но не до такой же степени, чтобы вываливать гору примеров на какие-то посторонние случаи - и ничего не сказать по сути?

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему можно назвать следующим образом: **постановка тире и запятой при их встрече в различных конструкциях**.

Если независимую  постановку запятой и тире принять за основной принцип, тогда  взаимное влияние будет проявляться в следующих вариантах: (1) тире поглощается запятой; (2) запятая поглощается тире; (3)  перенесенная запятая; (4) добавленная запятая (запятая и тире как единый знак).

**Тема 1. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.** Постановка знаков независимая. *Птицы, зимующие у нас, – это синичка, снегирь. Главное, чем знаменита Лапландия, – это то, что здесь живёт Санта-Клаус. Мы, коты, – любознательный народ.*

**Тема 2.  Обособление приложений.** Второе тире поглощается запятой, отнесенной к структуре предложения, это встроенная конструкция.
*Я увидел бабушку, Николая Ивановича – соседа по квартире, сестру Нину. 
Проходя вдоль своего вагона – нашего временного жилища, мы увидели в окне знакомую физиономию. 
Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике, и мы отправились на прогулку.*

**Тема 3.  Обобщающее слово.** Первая запятая вводного слова поглощается тире.  *В Москву приезжали торговцы, ремесленники, купцы – короче говоря, обладатели самых нужных профессий. 
Независимая постановка  запятой. И кресты, и далёкие окна, и вершины леса, уходящего вдаль, – всё дышит весенним воздухом.*

**Тема 4. Тире  при обособлении вставных конструкций.** Всегда ставятся два тире, вопрос о постановке одной или двух запятых рассматривается. В этой теме возможна перенесенная запятая.
*День, который она провела в Москве, – потом она часто вспоминала об этом – был тёплым, солнечным.   Издалека, – должно быть, из железнодорожных мастерских – тоже откликнулись низкие гудки.  Заключив тайный договор – его всё-таки пришлось закрепить на бумаге, – великое посольство собралось к отъезду. Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала.*

**Тема 5. Сложное предложение**. Единый знак.
*Сколько было слёз, сколько радости, – про всё не расскажешь. Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам (однородные предложения). Едва только раздались первые выстрелы, – ожила безлюдная степь, над которой уже смыкалась в далеких тучах щель заката (пропуск союза). Музыкант положил ожившую птичку на  ночлег к  черепахе.  Она  спала в коробке, – там лежала вата, там воробью будет мягко (однородные предложения).*

**Тема 6. Сложное синтаксическое целое**. Сложные синтаксические конструкции могут распадаться на крупные логико-смысловые блоки. **На стыке этих блоков ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие на взаимоотношения блоков, а внутри блоков знаки передают внутренние смыслы** [2.11.Знаки препинания в сложном предложении | hi-edu.ru](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-030.htm)

а) Ставится запятая перед тире (обособление внутри первого блока). *Не прошло и трех часов с восхода солнца, а уж казалось, **что близок полдень**, — так жарко, светло было всюду. Крупнолицый парень включил мотор, и мгновенно все успокоилось, затихло в воде, **плотно оцепленной лодками**, — ни всплеска, ни шума, ни сверкания* (Бонд.).

б) Не ставится запятая перед тире (первый блок — это СПП из трех предложений). *Когда называют Питер столицей, я не возражаю, **потому что это подтягивает город** — он как бы становится чище и лучше.*

**Тема 7. Предложения с прямой речью.** Постановка тире делается по правилам.

а) Запятая на месте разрыва слов  автора (**сохраняется)**, **повествовательная** прямая речь.  *Когда вы мне ответили: «Этого не может быть», значило ли это никогда?*

б)  Запятая на месте разрыва слов  автора (**заменяется тире**), **вопросительная**  прямая речь.  *Когда пешеход спросил у Эзопа: «Сколько часов ходьбы до Афин?» — мудрец не сразу смог ему ответить.*

Answer (score -1):

Да ни в каких случаях тире не съедает запятую, закрывающую придаточное.

~~~~~~~~~~~

Далее говорю о других случаях (не)сочетания запятой и тире.

Запятая не ставится перед тире при наличии указательного слова при оформлении прямой речи:

> После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того,
>   каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях,
>   когда в последующих авторских словах содержится характеристика прямой
>   речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка начинается словами так
>   говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает и т. п.):
>   «Ничего не случилось» — так говорил ум;  «Случилось» —  так говорило
>   сердце;  «Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» —  так описывает
>   эту местность один путешественник;  «Будь внимателен и осторожен!» — 
>   вот что он сказал мне на прощание.
>
> То же, если следует присоединительная конструкция: «Каждому овощу своё
>   время» —  эта народная мудрость передаётся из века в век.

Ещё. Если после тире стоят слова, выделяющиеся по существующим правилам запятыми (например, вводные), то первая запятая опускается, например:

> Сосна, ель, пихта, кедр — словом, все породы хвойных деревьев
>   встречаются в сибирской тайге.

Главное правило - Розенталь: [**Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении и в периоде**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_07).

Есть тире, [заменяющее запятую](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_07) (но не "съедающее"):

> При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные, реже
>   условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут
>   отделяться от него не запятой, а тире:
>
> *Буде спросит кто о чем – молчи...* (Пушкин); *Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять* (Гоголь).

Интересный пункт у того же Розенталя об отмене *второго* тире:

[Второе тире опускается](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

> ...если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится
>   запятая, например: *Используя специальное устройство для дыхания
>   человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки
>   метров;* *Еще одному виду деградации — опустыниванию, по данным Росстата, подвержено около 90 млн га.*