# Почему не стоит запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Почему не ставится запятая, какое здесь правило?

*Ирина Викторовна, мама Игоря, была очень недовольна тем, что Евгений Алексеевич передал вдруг мальчика другому специалисту **(,)** — она боялась, что я разрушу хрупкие (весьма хрупкие) достижения коллеги.*

Comment: Вопрос о том, когда тире поглощает запятую, неоднократно обсуждался на этом сайте. Некий итог можно увидеть здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет такого правила, чтобы на стыке двух частей сложного предложения («Е. А. передал другу» и «она боялась») замещать необходимую запятую тире. В этой ситуации эти знаки неравнозначны. На этом месте могли бы стоять оба эти знака, а также двоеточие.

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему перед тире не стоит запятая, закрывающая придаточное. Это ошибка?

Comment: Запятая ставится. Есть и варианты (см. ответ). Почему не стоит — это вопрос к источнику.

Comment: Источник - книга,  финалист премий "Большая книга", "Национальный бестселлер".  Вот я и думала: корректор пропустил или какие-то новые правила действуют.

Answer (score 2):

Arina, полагаю что здесь ошибка, запятая нужна.

Но вы неверно задаете вопрос. Вам надо было ваш тест в комментарии про закрывающую придаточную запятую в текст вопроса вынести. 
В точки зрения общего подходов к правописанию, все знаки в идеале ставятся на основании каких-то правил, а вот их, знаков, отсутствие обычно означает отсутствие правила на этот счет. Поэтому спрашивать надо не почему нет запятой, а почему нет запятой, требуемой согласно такому-то правилу. Иначе ход вашей мысли непонятен. И еще, давайте ссылку на источник текста. Иногда это позволяет объяснить необычность орфографии авторским стилем или историческими причинами.

Сделаю два предположения о причине отсутствия запятой у современного автора. На авторский стиль это не похоже, а вот по поводу самих правил...

1. Возможно, дело в структуре предложения. Похоже, что автор относит сочинительную часть "она боялась" не ко всему предложению до тире, то есть не к "была недовольна", а только к придаточному - к словам "Евгений Алексеевич передал". Другими словами логически придаточное не закрывается перед тире, а продолжается до самого конца фразы и состоит из двух как бы однородных частей "Евгений Алексеевич передал" и "она боялась". Грамматика вполне позволяет сделать такое предположение. Будет ли в этом случае необходима запятая после закрытия первого придаточного, правила ничего не говорят прямо, а трактовать "по аналогии" можно и так и эдак. Проблема в том, что правила о стыке запятой и тире вообще часто не позволяют однозначного прочтения. Можете посмотреть поиском даже тут на ресурсе.
2. В современной пунктуации наблюдается тенденция заменять двоеточие на тире (как раз в подобных случаях). Это не правило, во всяком случае не закрепленное нормативно, именно тенденция. Но она существует. Но перед двоеточием-то тире не ставится. Можно предположить, что замена на тире по логике автора тоже "съедает" запятую.

Первый случай - реальная проблема пунктуации. Не знаю, как его решить. По-простому - лучше просто не связываться и восстановить запятую.

Второй - ошибка. Надо восстановить двоеточие (хотя бы на время, пока эта норма не будет закреплена нормирующими источниками) - и все проблемы исчезнут.

Ссылка на источник

[тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=27QJDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=%D0%98%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0,+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F,+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83&source=bl&ots=tQUxhooMUZ&sig=hBaKrKQV5i9_dDs_WiEjhQt5N-c&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg2rCFmP_UAhUGQJoKHZpDDHcQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83&f=false)

> Только здесь присоединяется не член предложения, а сложное предложение

Это не принципиально. Тире может присоединять бессоюзную часть. У меня речь о том, что присоединяет не ко всему предложению, а только к придаточной части. Синтаксис понятен, но вот как это пунктуационно оформить - неизвестно.

> такие варианты встречаются в современных книгах.

Уже, возможно, потому, что правила на этот счет сформулированы так, что не все трактуют их однозначно.

Не буду искать всё, но вот хотя бы пример обсуждения на ресурсе. Вроде все считают, что все понятно, но договориться не могут. И там пример довольно древний один, это не только современность.

[Запятая перед тире](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это Анна Матвеева: "Лолотта и другие парижские истории". Знаете, а мне кажется, что такие варианты встречаются в современных книгах. Не знаю почему, но запись без запятой мне больше нравится. Наверное, действительно, присоединительная часть в этом случае относится именно к придаточному, как и хотел автор. Только здесь присоединяется не член предложения, а сложное предложение.

Comment: @Arina, Да я нашел её. Ссылку добавил в текст ответа. Это у меня было. пожелание на будущее. *Только здесь присоединяется не член предложения, а сложное предложение* - это не принципиально. Сейчас тоже в ответ добавлю.

Comment: Спасибо,  я хотела поставить вам плюс, но мне пока не разрешают (поставлю потом).  И прочитала обсуждение "Запятая перед тире", но вопрос  оказался сложным. Жаль, что в классических правилах он дается в неполном объеме, не все примеры рассматриваются.