# Основания для постановки тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть ли основания ставить тире в этом предложении? Если да, то что это за правило?

*О том, какая песня становится народной, а какая остается сколь угодно популярной, но все-таки «авторской», — написано сравнительно немного.*

Comment: Полезная информация о соседстве запятой и тире здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5

Answer (score 4):

Здесь скорее ставится запятая и тире как единый знак:

О том, какая песня становится народной, а какая остается сколь угодно популярной, но все-таки «авторской», — написано сравнительно немного.

[Розенталь. § 40. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)

**Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака** препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении:  1) перед главной частью, которой предшествует **ряд однородных придаточных**, если **подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на две части (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза)**:Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам (Кр.);

Comment: Но здесь ведь придаточные расположены не перед главной частью, а внутри нее, т. е. если было бы "Какая песня становится народной, какая...авторской, – о том написано сравнительно немного", тогда еще понятно.
В тексте встречается несколько аналогичных случаев, и я не могу понять, стоит ли оставлять так знаки или лучше ограничиться только запятой.

Comment: Правило состоит в том, что тире ставится для интонационного членения предложения , оно может быть авторским знаком и применяется  в РАЗЛИЧНЫХ конструкциях. Например:  Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал у окна я. Это авторское тире, заменяющее запятую. Но в приведенном предложении мы имеем однородные придаточные, поэтому при наличии авторской паузы ставим запятую и тире, хотя можно ограничиться просто запятой.  Но пауза/тире действительно желательны для более ясного понимания предложения, а это и есть основная задача пунктуации.

Answer (score 2):

***О том, какая песня становится народной, а какая остается сколь угодно популярной, но все-таки «авторской», написано сравнительно немного.***

> Есть ли основания ставить тире в этом предложении? Если да, то что это
>   за правило?

По-моему, никаких оснований для постановки тире после второго придаточного в этом предложении нет. Предложение свободно читается и с поставленной после этого придаточного запятой.